# How to format date with jsPdf and Angular

Tags: angularjs, jspdf

How would I format this with Angulars shortDate filter?

```
doc.text(44, 50, "Date :");
    var d = '' + $scope.currentItem.JobContractDate;
    doc.text(57, 50, d);
```

Comment: did you check the docs?  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter

Comment: yes, I am confused on how to apply it to javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it

```
var d = $filter('date')(new Date($scope.currentItem.JobContractDate), 'shortDate');
```